# Origin of the word "Characterstic values" of a Matrix or a Linear Operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found the synonyms of the mathematical term "characteristic values" of a square matrix/ linear operator. One of them is "eigen value", which itself (that I learnt) derived from a German word $``Eigenwert"$, meaning characteristic value. But I am not sure why do we call it "Characteristic value"? I suspect that it might have come from the notion that the spectrum of eigen values of a matrix/ linear operator, reveals some important characteristics  $i.e.,$ $ qualities$ of the matrix/linear operator, for instance, the $trace$, $determinant$ of the matrix/ linear operator.
    Is it sufficient to justify the terminology?

Comment: Eigen actually comes from the re-arrangement of the letters of the word "Genie" which are proved to be magical, as are matrices.

Comment: how do you justify your name?

Comment: Consider coming over [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-‌​and-random-talk). You might be interested since there are Indian students out there.